# Regarding Python's slice notation

Tags: python, slice

This line of code

```
print [0, 1, 2, 3, 4][0:1:1]
```

returns `[0]`.

However, the following line of code:

```
print [0, 1, 2, 3, 4][0:0:1]
```

returns `[]`.

Why is this?  Based on this [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation), my understanding is that the format should be:

```
a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step
```

So shouldn't `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4][0:0:1]` start and end at the 0th value, thus returning `[0]`?

Comment: `not past end` is incorrect - `up to (but not including) end` is correct.  Python slices are inclusive at the `start` end but exclusive at the `end` end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "end" index of a slice is always *excluded* from the result; i.e., `listy[start:end]` returns all `listy[i]` where `start <= i < end` (note use of `<` instead of `<=`).  As there is no number `i` such that `0 <= i < 0`, `listy[0:0:anything]` will always be an empty list (or error).

Answer (score 2):

The end index in Python's slice notation is exclusive. A slice of `[n:m]` will return every element whose index is >= n and < m.

To simplify things a bit, try it without the step (which isn't necessary when the step value is 1):

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[0:1]
[0]
>>> a[0:0]
[]
```

As a general rule, the number of elements in a slice is equal to the slice's start index minus the slice's end index. I.e., the slice `[n:m]` will return m-n elements. This agrees with the one element (1-0) returned by `[0:1]` and zero elements (0-0) returned by `[0:0]`.

(Note that this is not true if either of the slice indices is outside of the size of the array.)

For a nice visualization of how slice indices work, search for "One way to remember how slices work" at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that is `[0:0:1]` not `[0:1:1]`

So:

```
start = 0
end = 0
step = 1
```

The slice `[start:end:step]` means it will return values that are between `start` and `end - 1` with a certain `step`, so for your example:

```
...[0:0:1]
```

Values between 0 and -1, so it doesn't return anything.